# NSMutableSet count = 1, but that object is null?

Tags: objective-c, debugging, null, sigabrt, nsmutableset

Am using an NSMutableSet that is working great, up until this weird SIGABRT error popped up:

> 2011-07-05 17:01:00.249 Dama[1497:cd57] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet removeObject:]: attempt to remove nil'

ok, I can't remove nil, but here is my code:

```
    id item = nil;
if ([theSet count] == 0) { // This equals 1 !!
    item = [[[self getClass] alloc] init];
} else {
    item = [[theSet anyObject] retain]; //this returns nil !!
    [theSet removeObject:item]; // ERROR !!
}
```

Using gdb console, I found theSet looks like this:

> (gdb) po theSet
>
> {(
>
> ```
>  (null)
> ```
>
> )}
>
> (gdb) print (int) [theSet count]
>
> $1 = 1

How is this even possible?

<strike>P.S.: Am running in a multi-threaded environment .. I can't promise that the isn't being accessed by two threads at the same time, but it shouldn't be the case..</strike>

**EDIT**

Please, I really want to know how can the NSSet end up with (null), I dont care how it got there .. No matter how dirty my multi-threaded program is, This shouldn't happen, I think. [And I double checked, this set is only accessed by the background worker thread].

**EDIT**

> 2011-07-05 17:39:55.884 App[1608:c59f] Set count = 2
>   Contains: {(
>
> ```
> < Step: 0xc43f3e0>,
> < Step: 0x62f1800> )}
> ```
>
> 2011-07-05 17:39:55.886
>   App[1608:c59f] Set count = 9 Contains: {(

```
>     < Step: 0x62eece0>,
>     < Step: 0xc490660>,
>     < Step: 0xcb597d0>,
>     < Step: 0x65a4f60>,
>     < Step: 0xc43f4b0>,
>     < Step: 0xc43f3e0>,
>     < Step: 0x65c8f60>,
>     < Step: 0xc499230>,
>     (null) )} //null appeared?!
```

## HINT!!

Check out the `Step` dealloc method (xD):

```
-(void)dealloc{
    if (![[PoolStep sharedPool] purgeFlag]) {
        [[PoolStep sharedPool] doneWithItem:self]; //put it in the object pool for reuse..
    } else {
        NSLog(@"=== STEP ====> [ %d ]", --_counter);
        [children release];
        [super dealloc];
    }
}
```

## Another HINT!!

PoolStep is a singleton without @synchronize block in the sharedPool method, since it's accessed by one thread only. (and the performance is needed)

Comment: [theSet count] returned 1 .. That's whats confusing me .. not to mention the gdb output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping it and any other code that uses theSet in a synchronized(theSet) block, a threading issue could explain your issue. Maybe the null is caused by some intermediate state.

Comment: Problem is am accessing this set (roughly) once every 2ms (on simulator) .. performance is my number one priority...

Comment: You should nevertheless try this in a debug build. After this experiment you will know whether or not your problem is deterministic or a threading issue. 2ms is enough time to take the lock.

Comment: Problem is, it's random .. I just played the game for 10 minutes, nothing happened .. The question is: "How can NSSet Contain null?"

Comment: The answer is that NSMutableSet cannot contain null under normal circumstances.  An exception is thrown if you try to add null.  If it's a threading issue, you **have** to put some synchronization on.  There's no way around it.

Comment: if only one thread accesses this set, what's the point of @sync block?